# How to code an all browser supportable HTML project?

Tags: html

I created a site for my company, but it does not support all browsers.

[Opera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_%28web_browser%29) is supported correctly, but others are not supported.

In Chrome the header table does not display correctly.

In Mozilla the picture marque show few pictures only.

[Click here.... to view my site....](http://www.mcubicsolutions.com/)

Comment: Hello, Sagotharan! Stack Overflow is not a site where you would point people to a website and ask for bugs to be fixed. If you want people to help you, create a [small sample project](http://sscce.org/) for each bug you are facing and show us that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not exactly sure where you got your source code from, but it's a terrible mess:

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mcubicsolutions.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Fix it, and you should have less trouble with different browsers. Or consider using a CMS like Joomla, WordPress, etc. if you are not so fit in HTML.

Comment: its very usefull site. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you want cross-browser compatibility, you reset your CSS scheme using a reset sheet, for instance *[CSS Tools: Reset CSS](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)*.

If you stick to `div` and CSS layout, you'll probably be fine in all the newer browsers (Even Internet Explorer 8!). You can also use conditional statements in your CSS code to detect Internet Explorer (explained here in *[Conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)*.)